# GIT: I want to unstage all files matching a certain pattern

Tags: git, filepattern

I would like to run

```
git reset *.foo
```

but this errors out.

I think I need to use a pipe, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: these files have been staged as deleted. i.e. the files are no longer in my working directory. So I guess I need something like git checkout *.foo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for i in `git status --porcelain | grep '^D.*\.foo$' | sed 's/^D \+//'`; do
    git reset HEAD "$i"
    git checkout "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, the staged change was to delete these files. so, will this still work? the file is actually already deleted in the directory

Comment: No, that will not work.  I will update my answer with a new command.

Comment: ahhhhh, I actually want to run this on  files with pattern *.gen.cs

Comment: Hmm, that should work.  Can you verify that `git status --porcelain` outputs those files?

Comment: `git reset HEAD <file>; git checkout <file>` is equivalent to `git checkout HEAD <file>`.

Answer (score 9):

Now `git restore` is perfectly working, thus for me the easiest has been:

```
git restore '*.foo'
```

like in @César Noreña answer.

However, another pretty easy and very flexible way would be:

```
git diff --name-only --relative | grep '.foo' | xargs git restore
```

and it is flexible because you can use all `grep` options, or even replace `grep` with something else.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Powershell the following will work.

```
gci -re -in *foo | %{ git reset $_ }
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work in cygwin and unix env

```
git reset $(git diff --name-only --cached | grep *.foo)
```

Comment: Strangely with the asterisk this unstaged all files for me. Without the asterisk it complains about relative paths. This worked, `git reset -- $(git diff --name-only --cached | grep .foo)`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `git reset *mypattern*`

EDIT: Also try [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/), but be VERY careful as it seems to be bugged at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

In a Git GUI application like [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download.html) I would filter the displayed files by the pattern `*.foo`, press Ctrl+A to select all the filtered files and invoke the Unstage command.

Answer (score 2):

You can try restore the files with `git restore '*.foo'`

Answer (score 1):

E.g. I want to match all "migrations" in path.

git diff --name-only | grep migrations | xargs git checkout

Answer (score 1):

White space in filename was causing problems using the `git diff` approaches but the following worked:

```
find ./ -name "*.foo" -exec git reset {} \;
```

Execution is verbose if there are many files to be unstaged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *checkout* (undo changes) of *unstaged* modified files matching a given pattern, this works:

macOS:

```
git checkout $(git st -s | sed -E 's/^.{2}//' | grep '\.foo$')
```

Unix:

```
git checkout $(git st -s | sed -r 's/^.{2}//' | grep '\.foo$')
```

I've only tested this with `M` modified files. YMMV if you have renamed/deleted/conflicted files as well.